# acts_as_taggable_on using multiple tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a model:

```
class Cakes < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable 
  acts_as_taggable_on :itens, :types
end
```

Then I Have a form to write it separately like the documentation says to do, something like:

```
<%= f.text_field :itens_list, value: @news.itens_list.join(', ') %>

<%= f.text_field :types_list, value: @news.types_list.join(', ') %>
```

But when I do it, I'm always get the error: `undefined method 'itens_list'` and/or `undefined method 'types_list'`

I see the documentation and got an example like my code above. But I think I'm missing something. 
How do I to create, write and read diferent contexts of tags with the gem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As is shown [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#usage), you need to use the singular form for tags, for instance for `types`, you would use `type_list` instead of `types_list`:

```
<%= f.text_field :iten_list, value: @news.iten_list.join(', ') %>

<%= f.text_field :type_list, value: @news.type_list.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: I got the error: Unpermitted parameter: types_list. Then I add to controller at "params.require" :types_list and got the error "unknown attribute 'types_list' for News."

Comment: Put :types in params.require at the controller and tje error is gone, but the log says:   ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND (taggings.context = 'types' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)  [["taggable_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "New"]]

Comment: it should be `type_list`, not `types_list`

Comment: It seems to work now, but the form do not load the tags indexed when edit the post <%= f.text_field :type_list, class: "form-control tagsinput nmb valida", value: @new.type_list().join(', ') %>

Comment: Got tagger_id IS NULL again when change everything to singular

Comment: Did you implement [Tag Ownership](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#tag-ownership)?

Comment: No. Its just like above

Comment: You need to implement Tag Ownership for the `tagger_id` to be set.